# jquery attr("onClick") - ie and ff

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, I'd like to get the javascript from an A tag's onClick attribute.

```
<a href='#' onClick='alert("boo");' />
```

In Firefox: `alert($('a').attr("onClick"))` shows: `alert("boo")`

In IE 6/7: `alert($('a').attr("onClick"))` shows: `function anonymous(){alert("boo");return false;}`

How can I retrieve just the javascript, and not the wrapped function, in IE 6/7 using jquery?  (or plain javascript)?

Franko

Comment: Just curious, why do you specifically need to retrieve the 'alert("boo")' in this example?  Are you calling it from another place or just exploring at the moment?  If you're trying to retrieve the value for another reason, there may be a different way of handling it.

Comment: just exploring at the moment - was wondering why I cannot get the text / why the function is returned in ie6/7.  ie8 behaves like firefox...

Comment: @frankie boyle Ok.  I'm curious about such now myself but wanted to make sure there wasn't a different approach if you weren't just exploring. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, if you look at the `element.onclick` property, as opposed to the attribute, Firefox and others will also give you the code wrapped in a `function` object, as this is how attribute-based event handlers are implemented. As David Dorward says below, the problem is that IE<8 (and I think IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode) sees attributes and properties as the same thing, making it difficult or impossible to get the value of the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Thank you all for  your help / input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I retrieve just the javascript, and not the wrapped function, in IE 6/7

You generally don't want to rely on string values for inline event handlers at all (in fact you should generally avoid using inline event handler attributes altogether in favour of binding to functions from script — especially if you're using jQuery, where this approach is the norm). But if you have to, the workaround is the DOM method `getAttributeNode`.

```
var link= $('a')[0]; // or whatever
alert(link.getAttributeNode('onclick').value);
```

Comment: Totally agree strings for inline event handlers are wrong - I was just having a play and coudlnt see why IE was behaving differently... Thank you!

Comment: But then there is ASP.NET WebForms where a bunch of DOM 0 onclick event handlers are generated by default - I was happy to find this answer because I needed to mess with them... well, use them ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer <8 has a completely broken implementation of setAttribute and getAttribute which deal with the **property** with the given name instead of the **attribute**.

I'm not aware of a work around.

Comment: To expand on this: the value of the attribute whose name is 'onclick' of the anchor tag is the `alert()` call; the value of the property of the DOM node corresponding to that tag is the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

Better than adding **onclick** attribute is behalf of IE6 / IE7 this solution:

```
$("a").click(function () { .. anything to do .. })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
alert($('a').attr("onclick"))
```

In XHTML onClick is not the right version.

Comment: As IE doesn't understand XHTML (it sees it as malformed HTML) that's unlikely to be it.

Comment: using lowercase I get:

function onclick(){alert("boo");} - so same issue

Answer (score 0):

Browser safe :

```
jQuery('a')[0].getAttribute('onclick');
```