# how do we change onclick function via .attr() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got this url

```
<a class="remove_item' rel="4" onclick="javascript:jQuery(#blablabla)" href="javascript:;' >remove</a>
```

i'm using this simple find and replace

```
item.find('a.remove_class').attr({
title:'hello',
click:'hello();'
} );
```

but it seem it's not working. i still not able to replace javascript:jQuery(#blablabla) with another function.

Comment: Inline event handlers shouldn't have `javascript:`.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for doing this with an onclick attribute? jQuery was designed to be unobtrusive, which means that events are wired up outside of the markup entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set onClick you should use something like this  `$("a").attr("onclick", js);`

where js is a string containing your javascript code.

Comment: do you have any reference link that i can learn it more ? i know i can google it. but it better if you choose it for me. i have do the google and confuse

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page - all API is very well documented, with examples. Also http://www.heinmaas.com/all-the-jquery-resources-youll-ever-need/ here is the collection of useful jQuery stuff you'll need.

Comment: Be careful. You can set the `onclick` attribute like that, but if you try to get it using `attr("onclick")` you won't get the string. For me it's a bug, but it might have some reason behind this behavior.

Comment: Like BrunoLM said is getting the onclick string tricky in jQuery. You have to use the native attr method (getAttributeNode) - see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833973/jquery-attronclick-ie-and-ff

Answer (score 3):

Try attaching the event handler using the below code snippet in your page body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.remove_item').click(hello);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has no built-in way to assign event handlers in that way. Use the DOM0 method to set the `onclick` handler instead:

```
item.find('a.remove_class').each(function() {
    this.onclick = function() {
        alert("Clicked!");
    };
});
```

Also, don't put `javascript:` in you event handler attributes. It's incorrect and only works by coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.remove_item").click(function() {
            alert("You have clicked my <a>!!");
            //do other stuff
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The attr doesn't recognises the onclick attribute, get the html element (`.get(0)`) and use "raw" functions to extract the onclick attribute.

On **Firefox** the following works:

```
$("element").get(0).getAttribute("onclick")
```

You can remove by using

```
$("element").get(0).removeAttribute("onclick")
```

or setting a empty string

```
$("element").get(0).setAttribute("onclick", "")
```