# Prototyping with Variables

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to create a capitalization function using prototyping but it only works with text strings and not injected variables. I don't know what I need to change to make it work.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); });
};
```

That is my prototype but if i use it with `var addition = document.getElementById('addition').capitalize();` it returns:

`TypeError: document.getElementById('addition').capitalize is not a function. (In 'document.getElementById('addition').capitalize()', 'document.getElementById('addition').capitalize' is undefined)`

Any thoughts as to how I can change this?

Comment: try this `var addition = document.getElementById('addition').toString().capitalize();`

Comment: It at least got a return, but instead of a string i got `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Comment: ok, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470089/javascript-getelementbyid-and-convert-it-to-string
it depends on what kind of DOM element it is, so in most cases you would want to go with `innerHTML` or `value`

Comment: wow can't believe I didn't see I forgot `.value` thank you!

Comment: @www.eugenehp.tk That won't work at all. `toString` on an HTML element is likely to return something like `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`.

Comment: @torazaburo see my comments from late about `value`