# Why is my localStorage.getItem variable returning "object HTMLSpanElement"?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I've got a script in good working order that checks to see if a visitor has been assigned a coupon code but wanted to add functionality that retrieves the coupon code that they were assigned and displays it. Both rely on the *localStorage* property. The problem I'm running into is that when I display the stored value, it's returning `[object HTMLSpanElement]` instead of the value that should be assigned.

Pretty much everything I've found on the issue is due to scope, but I don't see how I have a scope issue...even tried making the variables global in scope and that didn't seem to do anything.

Here is the JS:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("visited") != "true"){
    localStorage.setItem("visited","true"); 
    var codeValue = document.getElementById("code");
    localStorage.setItem("code",codeValue);
} 
else { 
    var savedCode = localStorage.getItem("code");
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "You've already been assigned coupon code " + savedCode;
}
```

Here is the relevant HTML:

```html
<span id="message">Your coupon code is: <span id="code">CODE1234</span></span>
```

When you return to the page after already visiting it, I expect the span text to display `You've already been assigned coupon code CODE1234`, but instead it is returning `You've already been assigned coupon code [object HTMLSpanElement]`

Note that part of the script was something I had created before and put in production, and I'm basically piggybacking off of that functionality. Previously, if `getItem("visited") != "true"` returned false, it popped up an alert box and said you'd already been given a code, then redirected you to another page.

Comment: `var codeValue = document.getElementById("code");` – that’s not a value, it’s an element.

Comment: `document.getElementById("code")` returns an `HTMLSpanElement`. If you want the text, get the `textContent`. If you want its HTML, use `innerHTML`.

Comment: Probably a dupe of [javascript getElementById and convert it to String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2470089/215552)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are storing the element itself (which is an object) in the *localStorage*. You should store the text of the element.

Change

```
var codeValue = document.getElementById("code");
```

To

```
var codeValue = document.getElementById("code").textContent;
```

**Please Note:** According to [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

> The keys and the values are always strings (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

Comment: You can't store an `HTMLElement` in localStorage. It is storing the result of `toString()` in localStorage.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, you are right, updated the answer, thanks:)

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the text inside the element, here you are storing the html element inside the localstorage.
change the code to access the text

```
document.getElementById('code').innerText
```