# How to convert an HTML element to a string, including the opening and closing tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have the following HTML element:

```
<span id='kuku' class='lala bubu' value='xyz'>some text</span>
```

I know that `.html()` returns the inner part of the element, i.e. `some text`.

How could I get the whole element as string, containing `<span>...</span>`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Most browsers support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t05) the [`element.outerHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534310(VS.85).aspx) property. You may also want to check out the following Stack Overflow post for an alternative solution (for non IE browsers):

- [How do I do OuterHTML in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox)

Comment: Firefox 11 added support for element.outerHTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
alert($('#kuku').clone().wrapAll("<div/>").parent().html());
```

- clones the element you want
- wraps it in a div
- selects the parent (the new div)
- gets the HTML

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/NfF2J/)**:

```
alert( $('<div>').append( $("#kuku").clone() ).html() );
```

This one creates an empty `div` and appends a copy / clone of the element with id `kuku` to it. It then returns the innerHTML of that previously empty `div`, which now has in it precisely the HTML you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the owner of the span. So use the id of the owner/container of the span and use

> document.getElementById("urSpanOwnerID").innerHTML