# HTML5 Type Detection and Plugin Initialization

Tags: jquery, html, fallback

**PART A:**

I know there are a lot of things out there that tell you if a **browser** supports a certain HTML5 attribute, for example http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html, but they don't tell you how to acquire the type from individual elements and use that info to init your plugins.

So I tried:

```
alert($("input:date"));
//returns "[object Object]" 

alert($("input[type='date']")); 
//returns "[object Object]"

alert($("input").attr("type"));
//returns "text" ... which is a lie. it should have been "date"
```

None those worked.

I eventually came up with this (that does work):

```
var inputAttr = $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).remove().html().toLowerCase();
alert(inputAttr);
// returns "<input min="-365" max="365" type="date">"
```

*Thanks: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-get-full-html-string-including.html*

So my first question:
1. Why can I not read the "type" attribute in browsers that don't support html5?  You can make up any other attribute and bogus value and read it.
2. Why does my solution work?  Why does it matter if its in the DOM or not?

**PART B:**

Below is a basic example of what I am using the detector for:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
    var tM = document.createElement("input");
    tM.setAttribute("type", "date");
        if (tM.type == "text") {
            alert("No date type support on a browser level. Start adding date, week, month, and time fallbacks");
        //   Thanks: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html

            $("input").each(function () {
                // If we read the type attribute directly from the DOM (some browsers) will return unknown attributes as text (like the first detection).  Making a clone allows me to read the input as a clone in a variable.  I don't know why.
                var inputAttr = $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).remove().html().toLowerCase();

                    alert(inputAttr);

                    if ( inputAttr.indexOf( "month" ) !== -1 )

                    {
                        //get HTML5 attributes from element
                        var tMmindate =  $(this).attr('min');
                        var tMmaxdate =  $(this).attr('max');
                        //add datepicker with attributes support and no animation (so we can use -ms-filter gradients for ie)
                         $(this).datepick({ 
                            renderer: $.datepick.weekOfYearRenderer,
                            onShow: $.datepick.monthOnly,
                            minDate: tMmindate, 
                            maxDate: tMmaxdate, 
                            dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm', 
                            showAnim: ''}); 
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $(this).css('border', '5px solid red');
                        // test for more input types and apply init to them 
                    }

                });         
            }
        });

        </script>
```

Live example:  http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/sandbox/html5-type-detection.html

And a favor/question:
Can anyone help me cut some fat in my HTML5 input type fixer?

I have the functionality down (adds fallbacks to IE6-IE8, and FF with out adding classes to init off of)

Are there are more efficient methods for iterating over the DOM for mystery input types? 
And should I be using an If Else, or a function, or a case in my example?

Thanks All,

Joel

Answer (score 26):

A far superior method for detecting supported input types is to simply create an input element and loop through all of the different input types available and check if the `type` change sticks:

```
var supported = { date: false, number: false, time: false, month: false, week: false },
    tester = document.createElement('input');

for (var i in supported){
    try {
        tester.type = i;
        if (tester.type === i){
            supported[i] = true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // IE raises an exception if you try to set the type to 
        // an invalid value, so we just swallow the error
    }
}
```

This actually makes use of the fact that browsers which do not support that particular input type will fall back to using text, thereby allowing you to test if they're supported or not.

You can then use `supported['week']`, for instance, to check for the availability of the `week` input type, and do your fallbacks through this. See a simple demo of this here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/r5Wsa/2/. You might also consider using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for more robust HTML5 feature detection.

---

And finally, a better way to get `outerHTML` is to, believe it or not, use `outerHTML`. Instead of

```
var inputAttr = $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).remove().html().toLowerCase();
```

Why not just use:

```
var inputAttr = this.outerHTML || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this);
```

(Yes, as you can see, there is a caveat - `outerHTML` isn't supported by Firefox, so we're going to need a simple workaround, from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox)).

---

**Edit:** Found a method to do testing for native form UI support, from this page: http://miketaylr.com/code/html5-forms-ui-support.html. Browsers that support the UI for these types in some way *should* also prevent invalid values from been entered into these fields, so the logical extension to the test we're doing above would be this:

```
var supported = {date: false, number: false, time: false, month: false, week: false},
    tester = document.createElement('input');

for(var i in supported){
    tester.type = i;
    tester.value = ':(';

    if(tester.type === i && tester.value === ''){
        supported[i] = true;
    }
}
```

Again, not 100% reliable - this is only good for types that have certain restrictions on their values, and definitely not very good, but it's a step in the right direction, and certainly would solve your problem now.

**See the updated demo here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/r5Wsa/3/**

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply!  It has provided very useful information to help me make the script more efficient by using more JS in place of jQuery.  Exactly the type of info I was looking for.

Could you provide me with some clarifications on a couple items?
How does your input type detection code sample allow legacy browsers to unsupported HTML5 type attribute values?  That is my goal.  efficient detection of unsupported values.... not just detect support (like Modernizr does).  Perhaps I am misinterpreting that samples purpose. Thanks Again!

Comment: @Joel It doesn't try to emulate the behavior for older browser, because you've got that part done correctly. It's the feature detection part which I think is problematic - I know you're trying to use the attribute selector for this, but in reality generally speaking there's a better identifier for these form elements - for instance, `id` which is required for `label` s to work. Parsing the HTML of the `input` element is a very dirty workaround here.

Comment: It is quite an irony that the code used to detect moder browser features doesn't work if the browser doesn't support modern browser features (var ... in .. syntax). The fiddle doesn't work on IE 11, which supports input date...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo for... in is really old syntax. You're thinking of for... of. Also, no, I'm quite sure IE11 doesn't support `input type=date`  https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: @YiJiang IE11 doesn't support input type=date, but your test can't detect it because it failes to execute on IE11 :=) 
it is only a side note

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo You're right, it seems that IE11 raises an exception when you set `HTMLInputElement.type` to an invalid value instead of just failing silently like other browser. This has nothing to do with the loop syntax though.

Answer (score 10):

Asking for the type attribute does not work in all Android stock browsers. They pretend that they support inputType="date", but they do not offer an UI (datepicker e.g.) for date inputs.

This feature detection worked for me:

```
   (function() {
        var el = document.createElement('input'),
            notADateValue = 'not-a-date';
        el.setAttribute('type','date');
        el.setAttribute('value', notADateValue);
        return el.value !== notADateValue;
    })();
```

The trick is to set an illegal value into a date field. If the browser sanitises this input, it could also offer a datepicker.

Answer (score 3):

The type attribute isn't a "made-up" element, it's defined here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

...and browsers only "know" about the @type values defined there (unless they are HTML5 aware -- which has defined some new values like "date", "email" etc)

When you query the type attribute some browsers return "text" to you because if a browser doesn't support the "date" type  (or anything it doesn't understand) then it falls back to the default value -- which is type="text"

Have you thought of adding a classname (class="date") to the inputs as well then you can just $('.date').each() and then do you detection on that set

Comment: Oh certainly!  I don't mean to suggest that the type attribute is not real.  I was asking why you can't return the type value the same way you could return a made up attribute.

Comment: I had thought of just adding the class, but I wanted to have a fallback that was comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

**I would argue this is a bug in JQuery!**  If you look at the attr() function in the JQuery code itself, JQuery first trys to get a value for the name you passed in using bracket notation.  If it is not undefined, then it returns that value.   If it is undefined, then it usess the getAttribute() method instead.

Jquery does something similar to this for $("#elem").attr(name):

```
 if (elem[ name ] !== undefined)
 {
    return elem[name];
 }
 else
 {
    return elem.getAttribute( name )
 }
```

**The problem is Jquery is assuming if elem[name] is not undefined, then elem[name] is correct.**

Consider the following example:

```
<input type="date" id="myInput" name="myInput" joel="crawford" />    

var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

alert(myInput['type']);//returns text    
alert(myInput.getAttribute('type'));//returns date
alert($("#myInput").attr('type'));//returns text

alert(myInput['joel']);//returns undefined
alert(myInput.getAttribute('joel'));//returns crawford
alert($("#myInput").attr('joel'));//returns crawford
```

When you pass in .attr("type"), myInput['type'] returns "text", so Jquery returns "text".  If you passed in .attr("joel"), myInput['joel'] returns undefined, so then Jquery uses getAttribute('joel') instead which returns "crawford".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get type="date" in a browser that doesn't support this. If a browser detects a type-attribute it doesn't understand it overrides it with the type="text" (default).

A way around this (using jQuery) is simply to add the class date as well.

Then you can do something like

```
$('input.date').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.attr('type') != 'date') $this.datepicker();
});
```

Comment: You actually can get the type attribute in jQuery it is what my post is about and proves.  I was hoping someone could explain why the tricks we have to perform to read the type attribute are necessary.

Comment: That's not "getting" the type, that's getting the original html and "looking at" the type. You can't query that.

Comment: I think you may be wrong about that. In IE11 on both desktop and phone I get "date" returned from using jQuery to fetch the input type but neither provides a platform supplied date-picker.

Comment: True. But afaik, they still "support" the `type="date"`, even thought it doesn't provide a date picker. Maybe it does validation or similar... Anyways, I'm not even sure it's required by the spec to show a date picker on `type="date"`.

Comment: With IE9, input type=date is not supported, but JQuery will report that the type attribute is date, so this trick isn't really working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just `tester.type = i;` throws exception in IE. Fixed version:

```js
var get_supported_html5_input_types = function() {
    var supported = {
            date: false,
            number: false,
            time: false,
            datetime: false,
            'datetime-local':false,
            month: false,
            week: false
        },
        tester = document.createElement('input');
    for(var i in supported){
        // Do nothing - IE throws, FF/Chrome just ignores
        try { tester.type = i; } catch (err) {}
        if(tester.type === i){
            supported[i] = true;
        }
    }
    return supported;
};

console.log(get_supported_html5_input_types());
```

Always test, never blindly copy-paste !

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery script that detects whether the browser supports HTML5 `date` format, and if so, it changes all `date` field values to `yyyy-mm-dd` format, and all `datetime` field values to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format.

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10199306
// If the browser supports HTML5 input type="date", change all the values from y/m/dddd format to yyyy-mm-dd format, so they appear properly:
function fix_date_inputs() {
    try {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type','date');

        var notADateValue = 'not-a-date';
        input.setAttribute('value', notADateValue); 

        var r = (input.value !== notADateValue);

        if ( r ) {
            $( 'input' ).each( function() {
                if (
                    $(this).attr( 'type' ).match( /^date/ ) // date or datetime
                ) {
                    var m_d_y = $(this).context.attributes.value.value; // Because $(this).val() does not work (returns '')

                    var d = new Date( m_d_y );

                    var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
                    var day = '' + d.getDate();
                    var year = d.getFullYear();

                    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
                    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

                    var yyyy_mm_dd = [ year, month, day ].join( '-' );

                    // If we're processing a datetime, add the time:
                    if (
                        $(this).attr( 'type' ) == 'datetime'
                    ) {
                        var h = '' + d.getHours();
                        var i = '' + d.getMinutes();
                        var s = '' + d.getSeconds();

                        if (h.length < 2) h = '0' + h;
                        if (i.length < 2) i = '0' + i;
                        if (s.length < 2) s = '0' + s;

                        yyyy_mm_dd += ' ' + [ h, i, s ].join( ':' );
                    }

                    $(this).val( yyyy_mm_dd ); // Here, val() works to set the new value. Go figure.
                }
            });

        }
    } catch( e ) {
        alert( 'Internal error: ' + e.message );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think that the methods described here to detect if a browser supports the date inpu type are to complicated, if you'd like an easier approach you could just do something like this:

```
/*
 * Instead of body, you could use the closest parent where you know your input is going to be 
 */
$("body").on("focus", "input[type='date']", function(){
    let attribute, property;
    attribute= $(this).attr("type").toUpperCase();
    property= $(this).prop("type").toUpperCase();
    if(attribute!== property){
        console.log("This browser doe not support type='date'");
        //Pop up your own calendar or use a plugin 
    }
});
```

This function will be executed once you focus an input with type="date", it doesnt matter if it doesn't exist on the page yet, the listener will be watching until there's a new input[type="date"] on body, but as suggested on the comments, if you have a closer container that you know will always contain the inputs, well you could change it instead of having "body".

JS Listeners are fast anyway