# date fields displayed incorrectly on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the Accommodation tab of [this page](http://festivals.ie/show/741/music/barn-dance-v), there are a couple of date fields that use [this datepicker](https://github.com/Aymkdn/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap). Everything works fine on a desktop browser, but when the page is viewed on an iPhone the dates are shown below the fields:

[image]

Incidentally, I tried upgrading from the current (deprecated) datepicker to [this newer version](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), but it didn't work out.

Comment: It displays like this in Safari for Mac too, btw.

Comment: It displays correctly in my version of Safari. 5.1.8 on OS X 6

Answer (score 7):

I looked a little through the code and I found out that a declaration in one of the css included is what's causing the problem. You seem to merge all your style so I don't know exactly in which one is it (datepicker.css ?), anyway, the declaration

```
 .datepicker:before{content:''; display:inline-block;}
```

Is what's causing the problem. I don't know exactly the purpose of that in the grand scheme, but just deleting the declaration, or changing the `display` type from `inline-block` to `block`, makes everything all right.

Try to investigate starting from there,avoiding to break the style for other browsers already working, and understand the meaning of those `inline-block`, since they're present in both `.datepicker:before`and `.datepicker:after`

Answer (score 3):

Try CSS:

```
#booking label { width: 100% }
```

or something like that with width parameter
or maybe:

```
#booking label { display: block; }
```

Comment: Ups sorry, I dont get your problem right at first...
The easiest way to fix it: make special CSS for Iphone and use rules like this:
#checkin { margin-top:-10px;}
BUT! I tested your link on my iPhone and everything looks good (maybe you need to clear cache)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a third party datepicker, it is possible since iOS 5 to use a native datepicker:

```
<input type="date">
```

It is also possible to [check if the browser supports `input type="date"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193294/how-can-i-tell-if-a-browser-supports-input-type-date). You could go the way of using the native solution of the browser, if available, and use the third party datepicker as fallback.