# HTML5 date picker not working on desktop, only mobile

Tags: html, date, datepicker

The HTML5 date picker is only showing on mobile, it doesn't do anything on the desktop site. I am using the below html:

```
<input type="date" name="req_dobirth" tabindex="13" id="req_dobirth" value="<%=request("req_dobirth")%>" />
```

The same field on the mobile form is:

```
<input type="date" name="req_dobirth" tabindex="17" style="width: 92%;" id="req_dobirth" value="<%=request("req_dobirth")%>" />
```

(only difference being the width)

Any ideas?

Comment: Which browsers are you testing with? Not all of them support the `date` input type.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Comment: Sorry, should have given that info. Only works in Chrome, not firefox, IE or Safari (on mac)

Comment: Is there any other alternative that is compatible with more browsers?

Comment: the jQueryUI datepicker is a decent alternative that should work in most browsers

Comment: Yes, see the polyfill list I linked in my answer -- there are at least two date picker polyfill options listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it has support on IOS/Safari and Chrome/Opera on Desktop.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Yeah, had jQuery UI datepicker but diue to my numerous jquery scripts, it is conflicting so looking for an easier option.

Answer (score 0):

Most desktop browsers still do not support the `date` input type.

You can find a full browser compatibility chart here: http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

I suggest using a polyfill of some kind (maybe the jQuery datepicker control for example, or see the [modernizr polyfill list](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for more options) as a fall-back for browsers that do not support it.

See this question for more about how to detect browser support: [How can I tell if a browser supports <input type='date'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193294/how-can-i-tell-if-a-browser-supports-input-type-date)

Comment: Thanks for the polyfill answer, I shall look through that as looks just the ticket.

Comment: strangely enough, none of the datepicker polyfills i can find work in Safari, even when they claim they do!