# Check date and time comparison in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have `4 textboxes` for date and with each `textbox` there is `dropdownlist` for time.

Now what I want is,

> For each textbox date can be same but the timing should not be equal in all the dropdownlist.

for ex:-

if in each textbox the date is

```
textbox1: 08/02/2016
textbox2: 08/02/2016
textbox3: 08/02/2016
textbox4: 08/02/2016
```

Timing should not be same, it should be

```
ddl1 = 9.00
ddl2 = 10.00
ddl3 = 11.00
ddl4 = 12.00
```

What I tried is like below:-

```
 function ValidateRecord() {
    var StrPriError = "";
    if (document.getElementById('TextBox1').value == document.getElementById('TextBox2').value || document.getElementById('TextBox3').value || document.getElementById('TextBox4').value) {
        if (document.getElementById('DrpTime').value == document.getElementById('DrpTime3').value || document.getElementById('DrpTime4').value || document.getElementById('DrpTime5').value) {
            StrPriError += "Dates and Time for RA Reminder cannot be same";
        }
    }
    if (StrPriError != "") {
        alert(StrPriError);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**but it is not working even if I add different time. kindly suggest**

Also, see the screenshot of the HTML

[image: Image1]

**UPDATE**

The date format will be `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('DrpTime').value == document.getElementById('DrpTime3').value || document.getElementById('DrpTime4').value || document.getElementById('DrpTime5').value) {` -- this is an invalid condition always returns true.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: ohh, so what will be the correct logic ? any idea

Comment: The way you are checking the time is wrong. Moreover, if you have to check, you need to check for all of them as a `Date` object.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: yes, i have handled the date part. just let me know the **CONDITION** for checking

Comment: @coder - you are trying a condition `A == (B or C or D)`. That never works (usually a syntax error but in javascript the "C" and "D" are evaluated for their "truthy value" - which you don't want here). You need `(A == B) or (A == C) or (A == D)`

Comment: @HansKesting: so what should be the correct logic? i am also stuck in `dd/MM/yyy` format. which is the main issue. what is your **A**, **B**, **C** and **D** here ??

Comment: **A** = `document.getElementById('TextBox1').value`, **B** = `document.getElementById('TextBox2').value` etc. "or" is of course `||` in javascript. What I meant to say is to check for multiple values you need to check every value separately, you can't supply a list of values

Comment: @HansKesting: a piece of code will clear my logic. if possible let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are checking the time is wrong. Moreover, if you have to check, you need to check for all of them as a `Date` object.

So you need to do it this way, assuming these are your date textboxes:

- `TextBox1`
- `TextBox2`
- `TextBox3`
- `TextBox4`

And the times are:

- `DrpTime`
- `DrpTime3`
- `DrpTime4`
- `DrpTime5`

Now, you need to create four `Date` objects, which contain **both** the date and time. So say:

```
var dt1 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime').value);
var dt2 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox2').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime3').value);
var dt3 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox3').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime4').value);
var dt4 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox4').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime5').value);
```

And now you need to compare if there are any two this way, and you will get 6 comparisons:

```
dt1.getTime() == dt2.getTime()
dt1.getTime() == dt3.getTime()
dt1.getTime() == dt4.getTime()
dt2.getTime() == dt3.getTime()
dt2.getTime() == dt4.getTime()
dt3.getTime() == dt4.getTime()
```

So, the `if` condition for invalid value would be:

```
if (dt1.getTime() == dt2.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt4.getTime() || dt2.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt2.getTime() == dt4.getTime() || dt3.getTime() == dt4.getTime())
    // Error
```

The expanded one (for demo only) is:

```
if (
    dt1.getTime() == dt2.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt4.getTime() ||
    dt2.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt2.getTime() == dt4.getTime() ||
    dt3.getTime() == dt4.getTime()
)
    // Error
```

We are comparing all the dates, so you would get even if one condition is true, i.e., one date is also equal to another one, then you need to say the user it is an error.

Make sure your date value in the textbox is of the format:

```
YYYY/MM/DD
```

If not, this will not work.

**Working Snippet**

```css
label {display: block;}
```

```html
Dates
<label>Date 1: <input type="date" id="TextBox1"></label>
<label>Date 2: <input type="date" id="TextBox2"></label>
<label>Date 3: <input type="date" id="TextBox3"></label>
<label>Date 4: <input type="date" id="TextBox4"></label>

Times
<label>Time 1: <input type="text" id="DrpTime"></label>
<label>Time 2: <input type="text" id="DrpTime3"></label>
<label>Time 3: <input type="text" id="DrpTime4"></label>
<label>Time 4: <input type="text" id="DrpTime5"></label>

<button onclick="calc8();">Calculate</button>

<script>
  function calc8() {
    var dt1 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox1').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime').value);
    var dt2 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox2').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime3').value);
    var dt3 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox3').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime4').value);
    var dt4 = new Date(document.getElementById('TextBox4').value + " " + document.getElementById('DrpTime5').value);
    if (dt1.getTime() == dt2.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt1.getTime() == dt4.getTime() || dt2.getTime() == dt3.getTime() || dt2.getTime() == dt4.getTime() || dt3.getTime() == dt4.getTime())
    // Error
      alert("Equal Times Detected");
    else
      alert("Good to go!");
  }
</script>
```

**Instructions**

1. Use same date for all (say 1st Feb, use the datepicker).
2. Use different time for all (say `1:00`, `2:00`, `3:00`, `4:00`).
3. Click the button, it should say good to go.

Comment: Note that y/m/d format is not compliant with any standard, including ECMA-262, and will not be parsed as a valid date by the most recent versions of at least one popular browser currently in use (which is in compliance with the standard). Also, even for those that will parse it, some will allow out of bounds values and others wont.

Comment: "Best" depends on the criteria. Since there is an asp.net tag, likely the date component is a widget that the OP configures to some format. It should at least have a screen tip to indicate the format required. Anyway, the value of a select is a string, and if it's controlled by the calendar widget then the OP need only compare the string date values directly. But there may be other factors, it's a case of "not enough information".

Comment: @RobG Shall I ask the OP to use `type="date"`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: sorry, i forgot to mention the date format in my question. I will update it

Comment: @coder Forget about it. Use `type="date"` and it will take care of everything. See the snippet in my answer now.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: so i need to convert my asp textbox to input type = `date` and rest will be the same. Right ??

Comment: @PraveenKumar: ok let me try and check whether it works or not.

Comment: but when I take input as date i get error as `date is not a valid type for an input tag`

Comment: @coder That's a problem with Visual Studio.. Let's see what can we do to debug it.

Comment: thanks praveenkumar, it worked for me as per ur code :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar— type=date is not supported by all browsers in use, so it will not fix everything (or perhaps anything). There is zero input validation, so as long as the values of the time inputs are different, **any** input will do, regardless of whether it's a valid time or date. Note that if the date values don't parse (and it's extremely likely that they won't), then the Dates will be invalid, with time values of NaN, and NaN != NaN.

Comment: BTW, it's fairly [*easy to detect*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193294/how-can-i-tell-if-a-browser-supports-input-type-date) if a host supports input type date.