# Difference between dates JS

Tags: javascript

This is the script i use for the date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var datefield=document.createElement("input")
datefield.setAttribute("type", "date")
if (datefield.type!="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
    document.write('<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n')
    document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>\n')
    document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n') 
}
</script>
```

Alert is not working when the requirement is not fullfilled. Below is my code:

```
function validateForm() {


var x = document.forms["myForm"]["from"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("please choose the date");
    return false;
}
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["to"].value;
if (y == null || y == "") {
    alert("please choose the date");
    return false;
}

var date1 = new Date("x");
var date2 = new Date("y");

var diffDays = (date1 - date2);
var totalSeconds = diffDays / 1000;
var days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 86400);
if(days < 7 )
{
    alert("please be more than 7 days");
    return false;
}
```

I have problem in getting the range between the dates. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the variables `x` and `y` into the `Date` object as strings. Remove the `"` around them.

```
var date1 = new Date(x);
var date2 = new Date(y);
```

Comment: after i change it, it keep showing the alert even the dates exceed 7 days

Comment: Use `console.log(date1)` to print out the values of your dates and see what the issue is there.

Comment: where should i add it to?

Comment: `x` is your *from*, `y` your *to*. You then subtract `x - y`, *to* from *from*. The result will be negative or zero, and as such always less than 7.

Comment: mistakes like this can be avoided by choosing meaningful variable names.
why not call "x" "fromDateValue" and "y" "toDateValue" ...

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
var date1 = new Date("x");
var date2 = new Date("y");
```

to:

```
var date1 = new Date(x);
var date2 = new Date(y);
```

Also see [How can I tell if a browser supports <input type='date'>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193294/how-can-i-tell-if-a-browser-supports-input-type-date) for more reliably check if the date type is supported.

Comment: after i change it, it keep showing the alert even the dates exceed 7 days