# Jquery return element html instead of content

Tags: jquery

I have something like this

```
<ul>
<li class="aclass" id="a">content</li>
<li class="aclass" id="b">content</li>
<li class="aclass" id="c">content</li>
<li class="aclass" id="d">content</li>
<li class="aclass" id="e">content</li>
<li class="aclass" id="f">content</li>
</ul>
```

I have code like

```
$(".aclass").live("mousedown",function() {

alert($this.html());

});
```

This will alert the content, what I would like to do is alert the entire element like

```
<li class="aclass" id="f">content</li>
```

I've tried $(this).parent() but that returns the whole UL

Comment: exact duplicate of [jQuery - Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/jquery-get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alert($(this).clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html());
```

Comment: but...you will end up with invalid markup. Should clone the element first

Comment: @redsquare, very good point. I've updated my answer to take your suggestion into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('<div/>').append($(this).clone()).html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keegan3d/nfEyQ/

Answer (score 0):

To get the html-code of a DOM-Node you can use the property outerHTML

```
var html = document.getElementById('someId').outerHTML;
```

this sadly doesnt work in firefox. But you can use XMLSerializer to achieve the same result. Like this

```
var elm = document.getElementById('someId');
var xmls = new XMLSerializer();
var html = xmls.serializeToString(elm);
```

in your jQuery-code this might look something like this:

```
$(".aclass").live("mousedown",function() {
  alert( this.outerHTML || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this)  );
});
```

Comment: Seems like XMLSerializer returns proper XML, this might give unexpected results, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox/3819589#3819589