# Javascript, viewing "object nodelist"

Tags: javascript, nodelist

Doing an alert() on one of my variables gives me this result

```
  [object NodeList]
```

How can I see all the values in that?

Note; I am on Firefox and dont know how to use chromebug so its not installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can iterate the values in a `NodeList` the same way you would an array:

```
for (var index = 0; index < nodeList.length; index++) {
    alert(nodeList[index]);
}
```

Here is a good resource with some more in-depth information:  https://web.archive.org/web/20170119045716/http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/NodeList

Comment: that just alerts me like this [object text] and [object element]

Comment: @Ryan Try `alert(Object.keys(nodeList[i]))`;

Comment: it says: [object XMLDocument]

Comment: @Ryan - Yes, because the `NodeList` is full of `Nodes`.  Is there some specific attribute that you are trying to output?  If so you can do `alert(nodeList[i].attribute)`.  Or you might want to try `alert(nodeList[i].innerHTML)`.

Comment: @Ryan What about `alert(nodeList[i][0]);` ?

Comment: it keeps giving me back "undefined"

Comment: I'll vote each of your answers up and close tihs guys, i think my xml is wrong...

Comment: This answer still doesn't tell you how to serialize the object, see mine for an example

Comment: I believe it should be "nodeList[index]" instead of "nodeList[i]" since i is not defined anywhere..

Answer (score 7):

The better alternative is not to use alert, since that will display the object's toString(). Using console.log from FF and Chrome will give you a nice expandable object that you can click on to drill into it

And if you really need serialization, you can use outerHTML

```
// Firefox doesn't support outerHTML on nodes, so here's a method that does it
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox
function outerHTML(node){
    return node.outerHTML || new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
}

for (var index = 0; index < nodeList.length; index++) {
    alert(outerHTML(nodeList[index]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not tried console.log before... will look it up.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays I would definitely use the following:

Chrome, Firefox 3.5+, IE8+

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (var i = 0, element; (element = elements[i]); i++) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

IE11+, Firefox 24+, Chrome 30+ (with experiments enabled)

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (let i = 0, element; (element = elements[i]); i++) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

"element = elements[i]" is preferred over "elements.length" since:

> Node lists are often implemented as node iterators with a filter. This
>   means that getting a property like length is O(n), and iterating over
>   the list by re-checking the length will be O(n^2).

Unlike array access, which is as far as I remember O(1).

More details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll
- http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/