# Replace whole element rather than innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, mootools

I can do this:

```
$('my-panel').innerHTML = '<p> New content </p>';
```

But if there any way of doing something like

```
$('my-panel').wholeHTML = "<div id='my-panel'><p> New Content</p></div>";
```

I can't find any way. If I can't do something like this, I'll have to refactor a whole bunch of stuff, which would be time consuming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about `outerHTML`, which includes the 'whole' tag:

```
$('my-panel').outerHTML = '<p> New content </p>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Sah2U/1/

Comment: Huh, that worked. I should have tried that really, thanks. Is there an API listing somewhere for this stuff? The page I was looking at doesn't make any reference to outerHTML.

Comment: @Oliver: I can't find about it on MDN (weird) but MSDN has a good reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534310(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Ouch, just looking around a bit, apparently .outerHTML is non-standard and doesn't work on some browsers.

Comment: @Oliver: I wasn't aware of that, but I can confirm it works on the latest versions of Chrome/Safari/Opera/IE. Only Firefox refuses to do something.

Comment: There seem to be workarounds though, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You use mootools, right? you could easily replace the element, i.e.:

```
Elements.from("<div id='my-panel'><p> New Content</p></div>").replaces($("my-panel"));
```

Comment: Oooh, that's handy. I'll do that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you can always get the tags parentNode and replace his innerHTML

```
         $('my-panel').parentNode.innerHTML = '<p> New Content</p>'
```

Comment: That would work great except if there are more children of the parent element, in which case they get destroyed.

Comment: This was what the code was doing before I came to change it. The original writer got around the problem by introducing an extra div just for that purpose, but I hate doing stuff like that.