# Insert a whole element into another element, not just its inner HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to figure out how to use jQuery to construct HTML as sanely as possible. As far as I can tell, this should produce `<div><span>Alice</span></div>`, but instead produces `<div>[object Object]</div>`:

```
post = $("<div>");
username = $("<span>").html("Alice");
post.append(username);
```

I've found that replacing the last line with `post.append(username.html())` gets me closer to my goal, but it omits the `<span>` tags if I do it that way. How do I insert a child element with the surrounding tags, and without writing out `"<span>" + username + "</span>"`, which seems like a novice approach to the task?

**EDIT:** Stupid mistake. The snippet I posted above was excessively simplified; I was really trying to do `post.append(username + another_span_element)` in my code. Obviously I can't append objects like that. I've changed it to `post.append(username); post.append(another_span_element);` and now it works fine. Durr!

Comment: A "sane" approach, if you are using innerHTML (which is more or less what the *html* method does), is to construct the entire html fragment and insert it in one go. That way the parser is called once and it has a fully formed fragment to work with. Calling it in bits just creates extra overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me: `$("<div>").append($("<span>").html("Alice"))[0].outerHTML == "<div><span>Alice</span></div>"`

Comment: outerHTML only works [in some browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox) without custom support

Comment: @Marshall I was using it to demonstrate what the content of the element was; I wasn’t suggesting that `outerHTML` be used for anything.

Comment: You're right, it does work... my problem was that I was trying to concatenate two `<span>` objects in my code and then append them both at once. I probably shouldn't have assumed that that would work!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for not doing:

```
$('<div><span>Alice</span></div>').appendTo('body');
```

or

```
var username = "Alice";
$('<div><span id="user"></span></div>').appendTo('body');
$(username).appendTo('#user');
```

or

```
var username = "Alice";
$('<div><span id="user"></span></div>').appendTo('body');
$('#user').html(username);
```

or

```
var username = "Alice";
$('<div><span id="user"></span></div>').appendTo('body');
$('#user').text(username);
```

or any of the other 200 options?

Comment: Mostly because writing the HTML directly as strings doesn't seem 'right' to me. I'd prefer to work with objects and then construct the entire page at the end. Maybe that's a silly reason, but it's how I'm used to writing code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're aiming for is done with the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
post = $("<div>");
username = $("<span>").text("Alice");
post.append(username);
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Sxcz/).