# Is there a way to get the parent of .html()?

Tags: jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

I have this code :

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

and with `$('html').html()` I only get :

```
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
```

how can I get the whole code? I mean, with also the parent of the element where I use `.html()`...

Comment: On the one hand this seems like an interesting question from the technical angle, but on the other hand: why would you want to do this with `<html>`? For 95% of pages I've seen you could just say `"<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a hack:

```
$('<div />').html($('html').clone()).html();
```

Might be slow in older browsers with a lot of HTML on the page, because it has to clone the whole thing.

**Edit:** If you want a jQuery function which does it, just write one:

```
$.fn.outerHtml = function (a) {
    if (a) {
        a = $(a).insertBefore(this);
        this.remove();
        return a;
    }
    return $('<div />').html($('html').clone()).html();
};
```

Then just call `$('html').outerHtml()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this jQuery extension:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return (s) ? this.before(s).remove() : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
$("html").outerHTML();
```

Credits go to [this page](http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways, eq. `jQuery("html")[0].outerHTML;` or `jQuery("html").attr("outerHTML");`

**Edit:** This isn't cross-browser, I forgot that. Firefox doesn't support this. There are (cloning) hacks for that.

**Edit:** See [How do I do OuterHTML in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox) for FF support.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$('<div>').append($('html').clone()).remove().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, if you're trying to get `<html>` and it supposed to be the only `<html>` tag in a correct document - why not adding it manually to it's innerHTML?