# get self HTML code with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
  <a href="#" class="selected">link1</a>  
  <a href="#">link1</a>
</div>
```

and using following

`$('.selected').html()` I get

`link1`

as a return value.

How can I get full html code of the selected DOM element, in this example to get

`<a href="#" class="selected">link1</a>`

instead?

thanks

Comment: Yes. only $('.selected').parent().html() will work.

Comment: @Umesh this will not work if there are some siblings, which would be included too.

Comment: @Armin, View accepted :)

Comment: Why the values are not inside HTML tags, for example i ran the same query on textarea. The textarea is empty.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

jQuery object:

```
$('.selected')
```

become to DOM object:

```
$('.selected')[0]
```

**UPDATE**:

```
var str = $("<div />").append($('.selected').clone()).html();
console.log(str);
```

Comment: That'll give him the DOM object, not the html string...

Comment: Isn't this `clone` a bit painful when there's a lot of data?

Answer (score 18):

I know that this works on Chrome, don't know about the rest:

```
$("#yourElement")[0].outerHTML
```

That property is from javascript (not jQuery) and gives you what you're looking for.

Comment: Mozilla says it's now working as of Firefox 11:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML

Comment: Works in FireFox 47, IE11, Opera 38

Answer (score 5):

I made a solution similar to above, but with no cloning.

```
var test = $('#test').wrap('<div class="wrap-unwrap"></div>');
var str = test.parent().html();
test.unwrap();
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply using the `outerHTML` property may not work across all browsers. You will need to serialize it yourself for browsers without support for `outerHTML`. See this post for an explanation: [How do I do OuterHTML in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox)

Answer (score -3):

You could try this jQuery plugin: http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/