# jquery remove element by id and retain html in a variable

Tags: jquery

In the following code want to remove the html and get it in a variable.How to go about this.

```
<div id="tr1">Server</div>
var t = $("#tr1").remove();
console.log(t); // Should print     <div id="tr1">Server</div>
```

OR should `.detach()`  be used

Comment: `<ul id="tr1">Server</ul>` isn't valid HTML markup

Comment: Then use: `console.log(t.prop('outerHTML'));` if you want the output to be a string  http://jsfiddle.net/t354y/  Now i'm quite sure to don't understand what is your issue... Maybe you could provide a jsFiddle to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the element HTML as string, you can use the `outerHTML` property of the DOM node:

jQuery:

```
console.log(t.prop('outerHTML'));
```

Or using DOM node:

```
console.log(t[0].outerHTML);
```

Comment: Question : when can .detach() be used?

Comment: If you want to reappend later element, keeping event handlers (and data) previously bound, use `.detach()`. Simple DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8hcCB/1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think remove() will return you the HTML code when you delete the element.

To get the html code maybe you should look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8645992/3133256 (the updated)