# Get full html instead of just innner html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the html including the selector that I am using to get the html

let's say I have

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">content</div>
</div>
```

when I do `$('#foo').html()` I get

```
<div id="bar">content</div>
```

Is there a way in jquery to get the whole html including the parent(selector div)

I want this whole html

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bar">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to start off with, what about `$('#foo').parent().html()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#foo')[0].outerHTML;
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ifanap)

**More Info:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML

Comment: The second option would return the html of any siblings of `#foo` also.

Comment: Warning: This doesn't work in Firefox 10, which was released half a year ago. Which in most definitions would exclude users with an updated browser. So for a stable user experience, see Joy's answer below or any in  this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with `.clone()` and `.wrap()` like

```
$('#foo').clone().wrap("<div/>").parent().html();
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Vy5JW/

**Note**  `outerHTML` is not supported in firefox `< 11.0` You can check that in Browser Compatibility section here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML

So for a failsafe you can use something like following Which takes advantage of `outerHTML` if available and work across browsers

```
$foo = $('#foo');
var outerHtml =   ('outerHTML' in $foo[0])? $foo[0].outerHTML 
                                  : $foo.clone().wrap("<div/>").parent().html();
```

**Updated Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Vy5JW/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the `outerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML):

```
$('#foo')[0].outerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Sarfraz's answer, if you're using jQuery, you can pack it into its own plugin:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.outer = function() {

        return $(this)[0].outerHTML;

    };

})(jQuery);
​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WkH4z/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $('#foo').parent().html();
```

Comment: This will return the html of any sibling nodes also.

Comment: This will show the html within the whole parent which probably isn't what they want.

Comment: Given the markup, the parent had no elements so the quickest and smallest solution seemed to me was above.Thanks anyway for the pointing.