# Mootools Element to HTML

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools, object-to-string

My question is quite simple.. I need to convert an Element object into an html string

```
var thumb = new Element('img',{'src':"big.jpg"});
console.log( thumb.?????() ); //some magical method here
```

should return (as a string)

```
'<img src="_big.jpg">'
```

I've tried the `.get('html')` but it returns nothing, obviously because the img tag has nothing inside.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just proxy it.

```
var html = new Element('div').adopt(yourel).get('html');
```

Comment: yeap.. i've seen this solution on the net.. seems like this should work on all navigators... but it feels so dirty u_u

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`outerHTML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534310.aspx)? I am pretty sure all you need is:

```
var html = selector.outerHTML;
```

Comment: (+1 I've learned something today) apparently it's not compatible with all navigators http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox, and it might need some hacks. I wanted to know if there was some function on the core of mootools that could do that for me n_n

Comment: Actually it has been added, check out some of the answers to [get-selected-elements-outer-html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html). It appears that most browsers started supporting it in 2011.

Comment: that's jquery :P i'm using mootools

Comment: It is using jquery to get the element. `outerHTML` is just plain old javascript.

Comment: nah =P.. its not default javascript.. check this http://jsfiddle.net/pleasedontbelong/arjCC/ it works fine on Chrome and IE, but not on FF

Comment: `outerHTML` is a javascript option that was initially supported only by IE. It gained support from Chrome and Firefix in 2011. As for Firefox it started being supported specifically in [Firefox 11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_11_for_developers).

Comment: Also to note your jsFiddle worked for me in Firefox and Chome!

Comment: ahh that's it :P I'm using and older version of FF.

Answer (score 0):

> Returns a collection of elements from a string of html.

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Elements.From