# How to load content from specific HTML-element of URL using AJAX with plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml

I simply would like to replace the `<main>`-Element and it's content of `firstPage.html` ...

```
// ... header of my 1st document ...

<body>
    <main>
        The content of the 1st document...
    </main>
</body>

// ... footer of my 1st document ...
```

... with the `<main>`-Element and it's content of `secondPage.html` ...

secondPage.html

```
// ... header of my 2nd document ...

<body>
    <main>
        The content of the 2nd document...
    </main>
</body>

// ... footer of my 2nd document ...
```

... using AJAX call by plain JavaScript. How could I do that?

I am able to several methods to load 2nd document completely into the 1st one but I can't find any solution in JavaScript to load only specific HTML-element from another URL into DOM of 1st document. :(

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

This is my status quo of my ajax function:

```js
var myLoad = ( type, url, data, success ) => {

    var d = data ? ( typeof data == 'string' ) ? data : Object.keys(data).map(k=>( encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) )).join('&') : '' ;
    var u = (d && type==='GET') ? url+'?'+d : url ;

    var x = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    x.open(type,u);
    x.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if( x.readyState > 3 && x.status == 200 ){ 
          success(x.responseText) 
        }
    };
    x.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
    if( type === 'POST' ){
      x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      x.send(d);
    } else {
      x.send();
    }
    return x;
};

myLoad( 'GET', 'secondPage.html', '', r => {
  // of course this loads the whole document (secondPage.html) into <main>
  // but how to do otherwise ???
  document.querySelector('main').innerHTML = r; 
};
```

Comment: Show what you have tried? show your code

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I've edited my post with my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using AJAX to get a specific DOM Element (using Javascript, not jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458501/using-ajax-to-get-a-specific-dom-element-using-javascript-not-jquery)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks. I will have a look on that right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the [`fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the HTML as text.

Then you parse it to HTML using the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to get the new HTML and add it to the old `<main>`.

In this case, I added the HTML as soon as the DOM was loaded (`DOMContentLoaded`), but you could eventually change it to whatever suits your needs:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', DOMContentLoadedJS, false);

function DOMContentLoadedJS(event) {
    //fetch html as text
    fetch("/page2.html").then(response => response.text()).then(AfterFetchingHTML);
}

function AfterFetchingHTML(htmlText) {
    let main1 = document.querySelector("main"); //<main> on page1.html

    let htmlParser = new DOMParser();
    let htmlDoc = htmlParser.parseFromString(htmlText, "text/html");
    let main2 = htmlDoc.querySelector("main"); //main on page2.html

    //clear children from first <main>
    while (main1.firstChild) main1.removeChild(main1.firstChild);

    //add new <main>
    main1.innerHTML = main2.innerHTML;
}
```