# get the HTML for the selected including the selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get selected element’s outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

In jQuery I'm currently using this to get some HTML:

`var content = $("tr#add-ingredients-over-here").html();`

But, I actually need to include that `tr` in the selected HTML. I can't figure out how to do this. I also need to replace that with some other HTML after.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the *outerHTML* of the element. You can try this:

```
var content = $("#add-ingredients-over-here")[0].outerHTML;
```

This is supported by all current browsers. Firefox was the last to add support for this in Firefox 11 (March 2012); all other browsers already support this for at least 4 years now. If you must support older browsers than [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) has a jQuery-based implementation that works everywhere:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $(this).length > 0 ? $(this).clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html() : '';
};
```

Comment: Is it supported in all browsers now?

Comment: Yes, for a few years now. See the bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML for a list of browser versions which support outerHTML.

Comment: This question can help for support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox

Comment: Well, Firefox 11 was released some time in the first or second quarter of last year... I would not call that years ;) But good to know. I'm positively surprised about IE (but I guess they started it... some good things do come from IE).

Comment: wrap a `TR` in a `DIV`? IE likely to have a fit

Comment: @charlietfl: *justifiably!* That'd be invalid, and horrible, HTML anyway...

Comment: It's not inserted into the document - only created temporarily as a placeholder you can use innterHTML on, so not really that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another fully cross browser approach. Makes a clone of tbody, removes all but the row wanted and retrieves the html from it

```
var content = $("#add-ingredients-over-here")
                   .parent().clone().find('tr:not(#add-ingredients-over-here)').remove()
                    .end().html()
```

EDIT: WHy can't you just use `clone()`  if you need the whole `TR`? A clone  can be inserted in another table as a jQuery object

```
/*copy whole row to another table*/
$('#otherTable').append( $("#add-ingredients-over-here").clone() );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$("tr#add-ingredients-over-here").parent().html();
```

It will retrieve the parent first, and then return its HTML content

Comment: It will also retrieve all other elements of the parent. In this case probably ALL table rows

Comment: I did not understand you would like only your TR. In this case, you can create a temporary div, insert a clone of your TR inside and then call the html method. The code is: $('<div>').append($('#tr#add-ingredients-over-here').clone()).html();